# AngularJS - Why doesn't replace: true work with templateUrl property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pretty simple directive that I want to load the template from a separate HTML file. I want the HTML to replace the directive and so I add the `replace: true` property to the directive. However when I do this, the template doesn't get included at all.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kezbH/3/) where you can see this. If you use Firebug or something to inspect the DOM, you can see that when it's using just the `template` property it does replace the element. If you take off the `replace: true` you can see the HTML at the `templateUrl` getting appended to the foo element. However, as soon as I add the `replace: true` with the `templateUrl`, all I see is `<foo></foo>` in the DOM.

Is there some reason you just can't use these two properties together? I'm far from an expert with javascript, so any information about what is going on here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459) if you're working with tables

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make sure the contents of your html in the `templateUrl` has exactly one root element. This is not an issue when `replace: false` but becomes an issue when `replace: true` and you will see this Console error (with FireBug):

```
Error: Template must have exactly one root element.
```

Here is a jsFiddle of it [not working](http://jsfiddle.net/6sMgr/1/) (with two root elements) and another with it [working](http://jsfiddle.net/6sMgr/2/).

Comment: My html file had some comments outside my root level element. I figured comments were fine, but when I removed all the outer comments and only had one outer div, it worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone had any luck with using table row tags? If you replace the working example with tr td it stops working...

Comment: @toxaq For table row tags I switched the 'E' type directive to an 'A' type directive.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. If I'm not mistaken, you want to use "transclude"

http://jsfiddle.net/dandoyon/AsVp8/1/

Transclude allows you to blend your template with what is in the HTML. You may want to give the doc another glance and look for this option.

cheers!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, doesn't transclude just let you you put the contents of the tag into the end result? This is not what I'm wanting. I just want my <foo> tag completely replaced by what is in the template. The blah blah part in my jsFiddle was just to ensure that that part of the tag was gone in the end result.

Comment: Ok. Well http://jsfiddle.net/dandoyon/AsVp8/2/ (which I think was what you had before) works and replaces what is there. Am I missing something? Which browser are you using? IE does need special considerations shivving needs to happen for IE. Let me know if that is what is the issue. I wrote something for angular-ui to autoshiv our directives. https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/common/ieshiv/src/ieshiv.js

Comment: The problem with was with the commented out templateUrl property. There's no way for me to have jsFiddle hit my local html file, so I just put some URL it could hit. With the info mentioned by Gloopy I was able to figure out it was the comments outside my root level div that was causing the problem.

Comment: I hadn't be able to wrap my mind around this but finally it worked for me.
I run your example from chrome browser and I got the next error: 

  `Error: Template must have exactly one root element. was: <!DOCTYPE html>
   ...`

Probably there are something wrong in your template

Comment: What your error is telling me is that either you have <!DOCTYPE html> at top of your template (which you shouldn't have) or the browser was unable to get to the template and returning a 404 message with this at top.