# Repeating multiple elements with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to repeat 2 `divs` together, i.e. I would like to do something like this:

```
<!-- some ng-repeat="item in items" goes here  -->
   <div>{{item.name}}</div>
   <div>{{item.id}}</div>
<!-- end of ng-repeat -->
```

so that it produces a list of divs like

```
<div>name1</div>
<div>id1</div>
<div>name2</div>
<div>id2</div>
```

I cannot wrap my `divs` into an additional element.
Is it possible to achieve this with angularjs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-repeat with no html element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857714/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-no-html-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="item in items">{{item.name}}</div>
<div ng-repeat-end>{{item.id}}</div>
```

Note that this requires AngularJS 1.2 or later.