# How to output an array of different elements in a sequence using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code that generates a description of an HTML table row, like so:

```
  [
    {element: 'th', content: 'Header 1'},
    {element: 'td', content: 'data 1'},
    {element: 'td', content: 'data 2'},
  ]
```

I'd like to output these with angularjs, something like

```
<tr>
  <td ng-repeat="item in row" >{{item.content}}</td>
</tr>
```

Except I can't figure out how this could handle the element(s) that are supposed to be `<th>`?

(Vuejs, for example, has `<td v-is="item.element">{{item.content}}</td>` but I'm working in an angularjs app, so this example is given in case it helps Vuejs people understand what I need.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Clint's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57129114/623519), a variation that works with tables is:

### Create a directive that deletes itself (!)

```js
angular.module('theapp').directive('repeatSection', function () {
  return { restrict: 'A', replace: true, link(scope, el) { el.remove(); } };
});
```

### Use `<td>` elements to wrap the logic:

```html
<table>
 ...
 <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">

     <td repeat-section ng-repeat-start="cells in row"></td>
     <th ng-if="cell.element === 'th'">{{cell.content}}</th>
     <td ng-if="cell.element === 'td'">{{cell.content}}</td>
     <td repeat-section ng-repeat-end></td>

   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

- the `repeat-section` directive deletes the `td` elements that are created as part of the `ng-repeat-start`.
- we need to use `<td>` here - if you use `<div>` or `<repeat-section>` even, these elements get emptied (at least in Firefox), since a `<tr>` can only contain `<td>` or `<th>`.
- this works for my use (table cells), but is not a general solution - as you'll see I've had to include one of each possible element; that would get messy in the general case.