# Angularjs: ng-repeat and ng-switch on tr tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, ng-switch

I'm trying to use AngularJS to create a table of a list of events. But each event has a type, and events of different types have drastically different contents, and some types also generate more than one row.

In a perfect world, I'd do this:

```
<tbody>
  <ng-repeat="event in events">
    <ng-switch on="event.type">
      <ng-switch-when="type1">
        <tr>
          ...
        </tr>
        <tr>
          ...
        </tr>
      </ng-switch-when>
      <ng-switch-when="type2">
        <tr>
          ...
        </tr>
      </ng-switch-when>
      ...
    </ng-switch>
  </ng-repeat>
</tbody>
```

but this won't work because most browsers will discard or relocate the ng tags to enforce that the tbody only contains trs.

The only solution I've seen to related problem ([How to use ng-repeat without an html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490968/how-to-use-ng-repeat-without-an-html-element)) is to have multiple tbody elements; I'd prefer not to do that, but even if I do this, giving the tbody the ng-repeat and ng-switch attributes, I still have the problem that I can't wrap multiple trs in a single ng-switch-when.

Is there a way to do this in AngularJS, or is this impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the best option would be a directive that generates the appropriate markup based on your type1/type2?

You could probably also do it with ng-hide/ng-show, though that would generate extra unnecessary markup

Comment: I suppose I could create a directive, but I'd have to create directives for all the table markup, since the browser parses the DOM before AngularJS processes directives - if I put some `<my-tr>` directive inside a `<table>` tag, it'll get shifted to the outside of the table. So I think I'd have to build a slew of directives for table, tbody, tr, th, and td.

Comment: Another option that might work better would be to put your ng-repeat on the tr element, and then use nested tables within each row. and ng-switch on the row contents, but in either case have the contents of the repeated row always just be a single td

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem, best advice is don't use table:

just do a parent div id with * ammount of child div classes just like they are tr's and td's...

i haven't checked this in angular source but i'm assuming that the table elements aren't intertwined somehow, who knows..

Comment: Yeah, except sometimes you really do need a table. After all these years, there's still not another reliable way to allow for auto-sized columns of equal width that cross spanned rows. And besides, Angular claims to be the most HTML-in-spirit framework around. To hit a common use case where the answer is "you can't use markup that's been part of HTML since 1.0"... something is wrong.