# Comma Separated <p> angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a pretty basic scenario (somewhat new to angular).  I am trying to convert JSON:

```
[
    {'name': 'Nick'},
    {'name': 'David'},
    {'name': 'John'},
]
```

To:

```
<p>Nick,David,John</p>
```

But I can not figure out how to generate a single "p." How do you call ng-repeat inside of the `<p>`

```
<p ng-repeat="item in menuItems">{{item.name}}</p>
```

Comment: How about create a function in the $scope?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One thing that would be helpful is creating a "map" filter, like so:

```
myModule.filter('map', function() {
  return function(input, propName) {
    return input.map(function(item) {
      return item[propName];
    });
  };
});
```

That's the simple case of mapping to a named property, you could make it more fancy and understand dot notation, etc. Now with this, in your view you can do:

```
<p>
  {{(menuItems | map:'name').join(',')}}
</p>
```

Because the map filter returns an Array, which has a built-in join method already in Javascript.

Comment: Yea, this is the slickest answer

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. Instead, use a `map` and `join`. For example:

```
<p>{{names}}</p>

$scope.menuItems = [
  {'name': 'Nick'},
  {'name': 'David'},
  {'name': 'John'},
];
$scope.$watch('menuItems', function(menuItems) { 
    $scope.names = menuItems.map(function(item) { return item.name }).join(',');
});
```

This will `$watch` the `menuItems` and update the `names` property of the `$scope` whenever `menuItems` changes.

Comment: I dont know if its that simple.  I have a "MenuController" that that leverages a service, which calls json and returns it.  Right now its reused, and in one case i want to flatten it.

Comment: Okay, but I don't see the problem. The MenuController can call the service and assign the result to `$scope.menuItems`. The `$watch` will be triggered when `menuItems` changes. The `$watch` function doesn't change the value of `menuItems`, so `menuItems` can be reused as much as you like.

Comment: I guess you are always creating a csv version and adding it to scope.  So this would work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its possible... [How to use ng-repeat without an html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490968/how-to-use-ng-repeat-without-an-html-element)

But you can always do:

```
<p>
    <span ng-repeat="item in menuItems">{{item.name}},</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Coudn't find that one earlier.  How do you handle the $last case?  (No trailing comma).  Please dont tell me to use another span ;).

Comment: I got it:  `<p ><span ng-repeat="item in menuItems">{{item.name}}{{ !$last && ', ' || '.'}}</span> </p>`

Comment: You can also do it this way with another span :) : <span ng-repeat="name in testData">{{name.first}}<span ng-hide="$last">,</span> </span>

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that's more maintainable using Filters:

```
app.filter('commaSeparated', function () {
    return function(input, property) {
        var csv = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            csv += input[i][property];
            if (i < input.length - 1) {
                csv += ',';
            }
        }
        return csv;
    };
});
```

Obviously, you can replace the literal array with your $scope.menuItems...

```
<p>
    {{ [ {'name': 'Nick'}, {'name': 'David'}, {'name': 'John'} ] | commaSeparated:'name' }}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of a map filter.  That's cool.  For less code try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540667/1483977) answer.  Skip the `name` property and the `ng-repeat` and use the [join() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
<p>{{people.join(', ')}}</p>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
<p>{{people.map(function(item){return item.name;}).join(', ')}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use `<span>` instead of`<p>`, then following array of objects,

```
[
      { "name": "John" },
      { "name": "David" },
      { "name": "Gopal" },
      { "name": "Anil" },
      { "name": "Gurjeet" }
]
```

can be displayed as: John, David, Gopal, Anil and Gurjeet

with this code snippet:

```
<span ng-repeat="admin in data">{{$first ? '' : $last ? ' and ' : ', '}}{{admin.name}}</span>
```

Got this solution from: [AngularJS ng-repeat, comma separated with 'and' before the last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926345/angularjs-ng-repeat-add-comma-separated-and-and-before-last-item)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish that like this:

```
<p>    
   <span ng-repeat="(item,name) in menuItems">{{name}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}} </span>
</p>
```

I used this approach on a similar issue I had, I try to never mix javascript/jquery and angular. Got the solution from here:
[Using comma as list separator with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540157/using-comma-as-list-separator-with-angularjs)