# AngularJS ng-repeat, comma separated with 'and' before the last item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items ...

```
$scope.Users =[{
    UserName: ''
}];
```

In my view I want to list them like this assuming I have only 4 items in my `$scope:Users`

```
Username1, Username2, Username3 and Username4

<span data-ng-repeat="user in Users">{{user.Username}}</span>{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
```

The above expression will basically add comma after each item and works fine.

My problem is how do I add an `and` keyword before the last item so it will be like:

```
Username1, Username2, Username3 and Username4
```

instead of:

```
Username1, Username2, Username3, Username4
```

Answer (score 58):

$last is the truthy value.. so it holds either true or false and it doesn't hold the last element index..

I guess below expression should solve your problem

```
<p><span ng-repeat="user in Users">
            {{user.Username}} {{$last ? '' : ($index==Users.length-2) ? ' and ' : ', '}}
  </span></p>
```

Also make sure that you have the expression with $last within ng-repeat element and not outside of it

Please check the below working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hrishi1183/Sek8F/2/

Comment: `{{$last ? '' : ($index==Users.length-2) ? ' and ' : ', '}}` - This part helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 36):

This could be one of the solutions

```
<span data-ng-repeat="user in Users">{{user.Username}}<font ng-show="!$last">,</font></span>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Works like charm.

Comment: This is terrific, but it doesn't fully answer the OP. To add 'and' before the last item:  `<span data-ng-repeat="user in Users"><font ng-show="$last">&#160;and#160;</font>{{user.Username}}<font ng-show="!$last">,</font></span>`

Comment: I'm no HTML guru but isn't font deprecated for good reason?

Answer (score 22):

```
<span ng-repeat="user in Users">{{$first ? '' : $last ? ' and ' : ', '}}{{user.Username}}</span>
```

Instead of appending something prepend it. You can use `$first` to omit the first one. You can then use `$last` to add "and" instead of a comma.

Comment: This answer could use a little further explanation.

Answer (score 10):

### Use a comma before *and* to promote clarity!

> Bill Gates donates 6 million to Username1, Username2 and Username3.

vs

> Bill Gates donates 6 million to Username1, Username2, and Username3.

Without the serial comma, the sentence does not clearly indicate that each of the users is to be given an equal share.

```
<span ng-repeat="user in Users">
     {{user.Username}}{{$last ? '' : ($index==Username.length-2) ? ', and ' : ',&nbsp;'}}
</span>
```

Outputs:

```
Username1, Username2, Username3, and Username4
```

Comment: This strongly depends on the language. In German, for example, a comma before the "and" is not common.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem today, but with an extra challenge that the list items may need to be formatted within the sentence (for example, **bold items** or links). So just outputting a string from a filter wouldn't work. Initially I tried using ng-bind-html and outputting HTML from the filter, but that wasn't flexible enough.

I ended up making a directive that can be used within any ng-repeat to add the separator between list items. The tricky part is I only had access to $first, $last, and $index (not the original array or its length!).

My solution:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('listSeparator', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    template: '<span>{{ separator }}</span>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watchGroup(["$index", "$first", "$last"], function() {
        if (scope.$first)
          scope.separator = "";
        else if (scope.$last && scope.$index == 1)
          scope.separator = " and ";
        else if (scope.$last)
          scope.separator = ", and ";
        else
          scope.separator = ",";
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    Click a button to see the formatted list.
    <button ng-click="myArray = ['one']">One item</button>
    <button ng-click="myArray = ['one','two']">Two items</button>
    <button ng-click="myArray = ['one','two','three']">Three items</button><br>
    <span ng-repeat="item in myArray"><list-separator></list-separator>
        <strong>{{item}}</strong></span>

</div>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the text output, use a custom filter instead of `ng-repeat`:

```
<span>{{Users | humanizedUserList}}</span>
```

the filter code being something like this (using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)):

```
app.filter('humanizedUserList', function() {
  return function(users) {
    var last_users = _.last(users, 2);
    return _.reduce(users, function(out, user, idx, users) {
      out += user.UserName;

      if(user === last_users[1]) { // last entry
        return out;
      }
      else if(user === last_users[0]) { // second to last entry
        return out + ', and ';
      }
      else {
        return out + ', ';
      }
    });
  };
}
```

You'd save yourself the hackish use of `$last` outside of the `ng-repeat` and ternary operators - and add reusability for other parts of your application.