# AngularJS Getting an extra space when converting comma separated value

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I trying to convert a JSON content into the comma separated value in a table format.

I achieved this by using `table` with `ng-repeat`, but I am getting an extra space in end of the each value.

**HTML code:**

```
<div ng-controller="JsonConvertController">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnjsonConvert" 
              ng-click="convertJsonToServiceValues()">Convert Json</button>
    </div>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:100px;">Types</th>
          <th style="width:300px;">Values</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="types in resultJson">
          <td><span ng-bind="types.typeName"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span ng-repeat="type in resultValues | filter: {typeName: types.typeName}">
            <span ng-bind="type.values"></span>
            <span ng-show="!$last">,</span>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Controller code:**

```
function JsonConvertController($scope, $http) {

  $scope.displayTable = true;

  $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.jsonContent = data;
  });

  $scope.convertJsonToServiceValues = function() {
    $scope.resultJson = [];
    $scope.resultValues = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.jsonContent[0].types, function(types) {
      $scope.resultJson.push({
        typeName: types.name,
      });

      angular.forEach(types.domainTypes.codedValues, function(type) {
        $scope.resultValues.push({
          typeName: types.name,
          values: type.name
        });
      });
    });
  };
}
```

**Sample JSON** looks like, [Exact code is in plunker]

```
[{
"version": 0.01,
"types": [{
"id": 1,
"name": "Type1",
"domainTypes": {
  "type": "codedValue01",
  "codedValues": [{
    "name": "Type1Code1",
    "code": "t1c1"
  }, {
    "name": "Type1Code2",
    "code": "t1c2"
  }, {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  }]
 }
}, {
"id": 2,
"name": "Type2",
"domainTypes": {
  "type": "codedValue02",
  "codedValues": [{
    "name": "Type2Code1",
    "code": "t2c1"
  }, {
    "name": "Type2Code2",
    "code": "t2c2"
  }, {
  ...
  ...
  }]
 }
}]
```

So, the **output** is coming like the below:

```
Types   Values
Type1   Type1Code1 , Type1Code2 , Type1Code3 , Type1Code4 , Type1Code5 , 
        Type1Code6 , Type1Code7 , Type1Code8 , Type1Code9
Type2   Type2Code1 , Type2Code2 , Type2Code3 , Type2Code4 , Type2Code5
Type3   Type3Code1
Type4   Type4Code1 , Type4Code2 , Type4Code3 , Type4Code4 , Type4Code5
```

**Problem**: End of each value, I'm getting an extra space. Meant `Type1Code1 ,` after `1` and `,`, I'm getting the space.

I don't need that. How can I remove/trim that?

I tried `<span>{{type.values}}</span>` instead of `<span ng-bind="type.values"></span>`, but got the same result.

I manually set `trim()` like, `<span ng-bind="trimContent(type.values)"></span>` and in the controller, define the function

```
$scope.trimContent = function (content) {
    return content.trim();
};
```

This also not works.

Since I don't have any extra space in the JSON content. What is the issue?

How can I get the comma separated values without extra space in end of each value?

For better result, I added my code in the [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/efoweY4UpDt9BpRjhbrq)

Comment: Can you show the output HTML?

Comment: It's already exist in the question. After the `So, the output is coming like the below:` or you can see in the plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newlines in HTML count as a space. Just chain the spans together without spaces between them

```
<span ng-repeat="type in resultValues | filter: {typeName: types.typeName}"><span ng-bind="type.values"></span><span ng-show="!$last">, </span></span>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ybTEO8AvgU3XaN7tsRqT?p=preview

---

Alternatively, you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16673793/283366) and avoid the `ngRepeat` entirely