# Best way to ng-repeat information inside of a <pre> tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to use angular's ngRepeat or similar to create some formatted text inside a "pre" block.  For example, something like this:

```
function MyController($scope)
{
   $scope.data = [{test:'one', children:[...]},{test:'two', children:[...]}]; 
}

<pre>
  {{ngRepeat item in data}}
  {{item.test}}
       {{ngRepeat child in item.children}}
           {{child.title}}
       {{/ngRepeat}}
  {{/ngRepeat}}
</pre>
```

Obviously, I could just build up the string, but I'm curious if there is a way to do this in Angular templates.

Comment: Would the $templateCache work? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache#!

Comment: could use spans , prepend `\t` in nested children... then have directive on `pre` set in `$timeout`( to let `ng-repeat` digest) that does `elem.text( elem.text())`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ng-repeat without an html element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490968/how-to-use-ng-repeat-without-an-html-element)

Comment: You're best off just building up the string yourself. Angular doesn't actually have a templating engine, instead it works on actual DOM elements. To achieve what you want in your example you'd need to write a directive that runs its element's text through a templating engine such as mustache.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done you must have a parent element for it to repeat - i tried the same thing recently

my solution was

```
<mytag ng-repeat="x in y">{{x}}</mytag>
```