# Finding an ng-repeat index?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can do this in Angular.js:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cust in customers">
  <td>
    {{ cust.name }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Which would iterate through all the customers by putting each in a `<tr>` of its own.

But what if I wanted two customers in one `<tr>`? How would I accomplish that?

I normally do that by messing around with indexes and modulus values, but I'm not sure how to do that here.

Comment: how would the data (customers) tell you which to put together?

Comment: @nachinius Ah - they're ordered in an array - and that's the order by which I put them in. This is why I was thinking of using indexes for this problem.

Comment: Check out the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this can be done without any custom filters or changing the format of your data, though it does require some extra markup. I thought this woudn't be possible at first as you can't use a `span` or anything similar within the table for your `ng-repeat`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490968/how-to-use-ng-repeat-without-an-html-element) however, points out that you can use a `tbody`.

So it's just a case of using the `ng-if` directive (which renders html if the expression is true), the `$index` variable (provided by `ng-repeat`) and the `$even` variable (which is also provided by `ng-repeat` and is true when `$index` is even

I've created a demo in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/75lPORz9l9IPF1TAi66k?p=preview)

```
<div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="cust in customers">
      <tr ng-if="$even">
        <td>{{customers[$index].text}}</td>
        <td>{{customers[$index+1].text}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This would of course only work if you have two columns, what if you have more? Well you can also put a full expression into `ng-if` rather than just a variable. So you can use modulus values like this:

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="cust in customers">
      <tr ng-if="($index % 3) == 0">
        <td>{{customers[$index].text}}</td>
        <td>{{customers[$index+1].text}}</td>
        <td>{{customers[$index+2].text}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```