# Virtual elements for ng-if and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs. Not being able to find a way to include a couple of `li` items together inside an `ng-if`. Knockout had *virtual elements* doing the jobs, like this

```
<ul>
    <li>This item always appears</li>
    <!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
        <li>I want to make this item present/absent dynamically</li>
        <li>I want to make this item present/absent dynamically</li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Would appreciate help.

**update**: Enclosing inside a container like `<div>` or `<span>` is distorting the view when used inside the nav in bootstrap:

```
<div ng-if="!auth.user">
   <li>
    <a href="#!/signup">Sign up <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#!/login">Sign in <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Sanjay

Answer (score 1):

It's basically something like:

```
<li ng-if="conditionExpression">I want to make this item present/absent dynamically</li>
```

or, if you want to avoid scoping:

```
<li ng-show="conditionExpression">I want to make this item present/absent dynamically</li>
```

**update**
If you want to group several items inside one `ng-if`, you need to put them in a container, or just add a `ng-if` to each of them separately.
See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/s1z4a5L9/)

Comment: Thanks, but sorry - my question wasn't clear; have edited it now. I meant to know if there is a way to use ng-if to surround a few <li> items together, like knockout has *virtual elements*.

Comment: Great, thanks. So, we can have a container like a div in the middle of a running list. Probably an HTML5 feature I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Doesn't work with bootstrap nav. Have updated my question with code sample.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to use ng-repeat without an html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490968/how-to-use-ng-repeat-without-an-html-element)

You can use ng-repeat-start to avoid having to have an extra element with ng-repeat.