# get parent index of array in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have array of scope.students inside the controller. And the data is shown in my view form using ng-repeat in the table. What I want to do now is when I click the button, it should alert the parent index of the specific object. For example I click the button for 1 Brick Med then it should alert 0 because he is in section A. Then when I click the button in 3 it should alert 1 because he is sectionB. I am really new in angularjs any help is millions appreciated thanks

```js
var stud = angular.module("stud", []);
stud.controller("StudentsController", function ($scope) {
 'use strict';
  
  
    $scope.alertMe = function (key){
     alert(0);
    };  

    $scope.sectionA = [
      {
        no:1,
        name:'Brick Med',
      },
      {
        no:2,
        name: 'Colin Christopher',
      },
    ];
      
     $scope.sectionB = [
      {
        no:3,
        name: 'Frank Joemar Timbang',
      },
      {
        no:4,
        name: 'Curtis Zaymond',
      }
      ];
    
    $scope.students = [
      $scope.sectionA,
      $scope.sectionB
    ];

     

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="stud">
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Tally Boxes</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="StudentsController" data-ng-init="init()">
  <div id="container">
   </div>
  <div class="container-table">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Students</td>
                <td>Alert</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in students[0]">
                <td>{{value.no}} {{value.name}}</td>
              <td><button ng-click="alertMe(key)">Alert me!</button></td>
                 
            </tr>
           <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in students[1]">
                <td>{{value.no}} {{value.name}}</td>
              <td><button ng-click="alertMe(key)">Alert me!</button></td>
                 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>

  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="tallyboxController.js"></script>
  <script src="tallyboxDirective.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your final code, but you have the `students` indexes hard-coded, so when you're calling `alertMe`, you already know whether the index is 0 or 1.

Comment: yes but I need when I click the alert me button it should display what is their parent index. I

Comment: You already have it harcoded like `students[0]` so you know it is going to be 0 so just pass 0 (and other index respectively) ?

Comment: Hello PSL. How can I pass 0 to my controller, I tried it before but I do not know how to pass it. Can you guide me?

Comment: Okay I edited my code and I add alert in $scope.alertMe(), but when I click the button it all alert 0, what is my mistakes :-(

Comment: i dint say alert(0) did i? :D i said `ng-click="alertMe(0)"` and `ng-click="alertMe(1)"` and in your controller method do alert(key)

Comment: @PSL mean you pass <td><button ng-click="alertMe(0)">Alert me!</button></td> in html, for alertMe function in js, you just alert(key), why don't you change the json into one array?

Comment: @huanfeng can you help me how can I change my json into one array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` is a bit of a mess, but I'm guessing this is what you want to do:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="studentGroup in students">
    <tr ng-repeat="student in studentGroup">
        <td>{{student.no}} {{student.name}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="alertMe($parent.$index)">Alert me!</button></td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Note that `(key, value)` is for when you're iterating over an object's properties, but `students` is an array.

For the `$parent.$index`, see [Access index of the parent ng-repeat from child ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807258/access-index-of-the-parent-ng-repeat-from-child-ng-repeat)

For the `tbody ng-repeat` see [How to use ng-repeat without an html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490968/how-to-use-ng-repeat-without-an-html-element)

---

You could avoid using `$parent.$index` by changing the `ng-click` to `alertMe(studentGroup)` and `$scope.alertMe` to

```
$scope.alertMe = function (studentGroup) {
    alert($scope.students.indexOf(studentGroup));
};
```

But it depends on your final usage which one you'd prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much @David Williams. Your answer is what I need.

Comment: What if I want to shows only the sectionA in the table and I want when I click the alert me button again it should still alert its parent index?

Comment: It really depends on how this will scale. For that specific scenario, you could add `ng-show="$first"` to the `tbody`, but that assumes you only ever want to show sectionA.

A better way would be to convert SectionA and SectionB into objects, with a property called `show` and another called `students`. Then add `ng-show="studentGroup.show"` and update the inner `ng-repeat` to use `studentGroup.students`.

Comment: OMG I think it's tough lol. I will try to convert them in objects. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I already convert my Section A and Section B in objects.  http://jsfiddle.net/e4toyd6j/

Comment: THe code is not working on mine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your fiddle is lacking javascript.

Comment: Yeah it looks fine. If it's not working, it'll be something in your controller.

Comment: This is the updated fiddle. The fiddle is not running. I just want to show you how I convert my array to object. Please check :-) http://jsfiddle.net/DharkRoses/7kLo51v7/

Comment: You've made `candidates` an object now, so you want to iterate over it as you were originally with `(key, candidateGroup) in candidates`, although you can now no longer do `candidateGroup.show` because `candidateGroup` (ie. `presidents` or `vicePresidents`) are arrays.