# Setting bindings for a directive that has a templateURL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm not having any luck setting the bindings within a directive that fetches a template from a templateUrl.

Here's what the inside of my binding code looks like:

```
templateUrl : '/path/to/template.html',
link : function($scope, element, attrs) {
  $scope.title = 'test';
}
```

And here's what the template itself looks like:

```
<div>
  <h4>{{title}}</h4>
</div>
```

The directive is fired for a data-video attribute. The directive itself gets fired and downloads the template, but the scope bindings are not replaced.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have looks good to me here are some suggestions:

- If `{{title}` isn't a typo make sure you use `{{title}}` instead.
- The demo at the bottom of the directive [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) shows something similar in case that helps.
- Make sure your template isn't being cached and causing confusion by making some noticeable changes and making sure you see it on refresh.
- If you have `replace: true` set make sure your html file doesn't have any comments outside the root level per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426114/angularjs-why-doesnt-replace-true-work-with-templateurl-property).
- The link function's scope doesn't need a $ but I don't think that will affect anything: `function(scope, element, attrs)`

Comment: My mistake. It was a typo. Good thing that this up here at least for others to see. Thank you :)